# Drawing convexity relations diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows

[image]

How to draw the above diagram in LaTeX. Using TikZ? Please help me out.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: With `tikz-cd`. This being said, the text alignment is not clear.

Comment: @Photo: Was this printed on a wall?

Answer (score 4):

Since you would like `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
    row sep=large,
    column sep=large,
    arrows={Rightarrow}
    ]
\text{strict convexity}\ar[r]\ar[d,"\text{(under differentiability)}" description]  & \text{convexity}\ar[d,"\text{(under differentiability)}" description] \\
\text{strict pseudoconvexity}\ar[d]\ar[r] &  \text{pseudoconvexity}\ar[d] \\
\text{strict quasiconvexity}\ar[r] &  \text{quasiconvexity} \\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Meow meow meow!

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat lol

Comment: its good, thanks, is there any website to make tikzcd ?

Comment: please tell me, if there is any website

Comment: @vivekdhingra Try this https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/

Comment: but how to get right arrow there?

Comment: @vivekdhingra For the arrows there is a button on the bottom of the windows. I don't know how to change the arrow shape with that tool, I've never used it, I've always drawn the TikZ cd in LaTeX directly, sorry.

Comment: anyhow thanks a lot sir

Comment: @vivekdhingra You're welcome, but I'm a woman :)

Answer (score 3):

Does it have to be TikZ? Maybe a simple tabular is enough:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
strict convexity & $\Rightarrow$ & convexity \\
$\Downarrow$ & & $\Downarrow$ \\
strict  & $\Rightarrow$ & convex \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: no, i need full

Comment: Ok, I understand. So gimme a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 3):

You can have this diagram with a simple `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
\begin{tabular}{r@{}c@{}l}
  strict convexity & $\implies $ & convexity \\
\makecell{$\Vert$} & & \makecell{$\Vert\qquad$} \\
\multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (under differentiability)} & & \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\rlap{\footnotesize (under differentiability)}}\\[-0.4ex]
\makecell{$\Downarrow$} & & \makecell{$\Downarrow\qquad$} \\
strict pseudoconvexity & $\implies $ & pseudoconvexity \\[-0.4ex]
\makecell{$\Downarrow$} & & \makecell{$\Downarrow\qquad$} \\
strict quasiconvexity & $\implies $ & quasiconvexity
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have overlooked the overwritten arrow. So I think you want something like that:

[image]

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\matrix (m)[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
row sep=1.5em, %column sep=1em, 
nodes={fill=white, text width=3cm, align=center},
column 2/.style={nodes={text width=2em}}
]{
strict convexity &   & convexity \\
strict  &   & convex \\
very strict  &   & very convex \\
};

% Arrows 
\tikzset{imparrow/.style={double, double distance=1.5pt,  -{Implies[]}}}
\draw[imparrow] (m-1-1) -- (m-1-3);
\draw[imparrow] (m-3-1) -- (m-3-3);
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[imparrow] (m-1-1) -- (m-3-1);
\draw[imparrow] (m-1-3) -- (m-3-3);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick sketchup of what you want. The arrows are defined in the \draw tags, so you'll be able to change the style in there somewhere. Good luck!

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
        \node(sc){Strict Convexivity};
        \node[below = 1cm of sc](ud){(Under differentiability)};
        \node[below = 1cm of ud](sp){strict pseudoconvexivity};
        \node[below = 1cm of sp](sq){Strict quasiconvexivity};

        \draw[-latex] (sc.south) -- (ud.north);
        \draw[-latex] (ud.south) -- (sp.north);
        \draw[-latex] (sp.south) -- (sq.north);

        \node[right = 4cm of sc] (c){Convexivity};
        \node[below = 1cm of c](ud2){(Under differentiability)};
        \node[below = 1cm of ud2](p){strict pseudoconvexivity};
        \node[below = 1cm of p](q){Strict quasiconvexivity};

        \draw[-latex] (c.south) -- (ud2.north);
        \draw[-latex] (ud2.south) -- (p.north);
        \draw[-latex] (p.south) -- (q.north);    

        \draw[-latex] (sc.east) -- (c.west);
        \draw[-latex] (sp.east) -- (p.west);
        \draw[-latex] (sq.east) --  (q.west);      

  \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Tikz output (I was using Beamer at the time, so yours may look different)]

**Nodes**

[below = 1cm of sc] positions this node 1cm under the node labelled sc

(ud) sets the label of the current node to ud

{(Under differentiability)} sets the text of the current node to "(Under differentiability)"

```
\node[below = 1cm of sc](ud){(Under differentiability)};
```

**Lines**

This draws an arrow from the bottom (south) of the node labelled c, to the top 
(north) of the node labelled ud2.

```
\draw[-latex] (c.south) -- (ud2.north);
```

Comment: it works.. thanks for this.

Comment: No problem. I think the answer in the comment by @cis is neater, though.

Comment: It is usually easier to use `\usetikzlibrary {matrix}` for that kind of layout. See my TikZ-answer.